# Laravel request()->fullUrlWithQuery() doesn't work as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying create a paging on my page using the

```
request()->fullUrlWithQuery(["page" =>$page_number])
```

However, instead of getting the full url with query params with the `page` param appended to it. I get only the path with the `page` param appended

```
@for($i = 1; $i<=$pagesCount;$i++)
    <li class="page-item {{request()->get("page") == $i ? 'active' :""}}">
        <a class="page-link"
           href="{{request()->fullUrlWithQuery(["page" =>$i])}}">{{$i}}</a>
    </li>
@endfor
```

The original url

```
http://localhost:8899/offers/find?make=&year=&location=&drive=&color=&min_original_price=&max_original_price=&currency=
```

and when I output:

```
{{request()->fullUrlWithQuery(["page" =>1])}}
</br>
{{request()->fullUrl()}}
</br>
```

I get

```
http://localhost:8899/offers/find?page=1
```

and

```
http://localhost:8899/offers/find?color=&currency=&drive=&location=&make=&max_original_price=&min_original_price=&year=
```

respectively.

Comment: All your query parameters are empty. Does it change anything when they have a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your query parameters are `null`.

[`fullUrlWithQuery()` uses `Illuminate\Support\Arr::query()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cf8b2755c88b72eb147ee5e32eb5bc452cf6470e/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L127).

[`Illuminate\Support\Arr::query()` in turn uses the native `http_build_query()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php#L532).

Unfortunately for your use case, `http_build_query()` will drop parameters which are null:

```php
// returns "test2=data"
http_build_query(["test"=>null,"test2"=>"data"]);
```

If you want your query parameters which are `null` to show up in the path you're generating, you'll need to write some custom code in your controller to handle that.

I suggest using [the code linked here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#121556) to parse the URL generated by `fullUrl()`, adding the page number to the resulting array, setting all `null` values in the array to the empty string `""`, then passing the resulting array to `http_build_query()`.

Personally, I think a better pattern is for your controller to be able to handle queries that are missing the parameters you expect.

*P.S. The reason `fullUrl()` doesn't drop the parameters which are `null` is because it isn't merging arrays, so it doesn't call `Arr::query()` - [code for reference](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cf8b2755c88b72eb147ee5e32eb5bc452cf6470e/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L112)*

Answer (score 0):

If this was a named route it would be simpler, but only using `request()` to build the url, I think you can get this to work with `tap()`

```xml
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagesCount; $i++)
  <li class="page-item {{ request()->get('page') == $i ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a class="page-link"
      href="{{ tap(request(), fn($r) => $r->query->add(['page' => $i]))->fullUrlWithQuery([]) }}">
      {{ $i }}
    </a>
  </li>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more of a hack and it works. It is probably not the best answer out there but short and it works.

```
request()->fullUrlWithQuery(array_merge(request()->all(), ["page" => $user->id]))
```

This should return:

```
http://localhost:8899/offers/find?color=1&params=more-params&page=1
```

Comment: This will fail if the user is on `http://localhost:8899/offers/find`.

Comment: Unless I got your question above wrong, what you intended to do was to only append `page=1 ` on to the current the full url via `request()->fullUrlWithQuery(["page" =>1])` but what you got was missing the previous get request parameters i.e `make=&year=&location=&drive=&color=&min_original_price=&max_original_price=&currency=...`. Right?
If your answer is affirmative, my solution addresses this issue only.

Comment: It's not my question, but it's highly likely that at some point users will be on the URL without a query string at all. In these cases, your code will fail, due to the lack of a `?` in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Please check it now!